# CSS centering before element larger than screen

Tags: html, css

I've got a css before element which I would like to have centered in the screen regardless of the screen size. The before element has an image in it. No matter what I've tried, it still sits left aligned.

```
footer{
    position: relative;
    padding: 20em 0 2em;
    color: #fff;
}
footer::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 1371px;
    background: url(../images/el-footer.svg) center top no-repeat;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
}
```

I have also tried adding in `left:50%` and `transform:translateX(-50%)`, but all that does is sit it left 50%.

If someone could help me out, or point me in the right direction of how to make this always be centered, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set width/height to the relative container and position the image in the ::before tag.

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 20em 0 2em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/320/240) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  lorem ipsum
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center your image horizontally, you can use the following properties on your `:before` element:

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```